# How do I prevent access to website by IP on kestrel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webserver, .net-6.0, kestrel

I have a aspnet core 6.0 web app running on port 443 using kestrel on Ubuntu 20.04. The certificate and origin pulls are set up and all work!

However, I can still access my site by going to `https://<my server ip>`.

Is there a way I can prevent access this way?

My appsettings.json:

```
"Kestrel": {
"HttpsDefaults": {
  "ClientCertificateMode": "RequireCertificate"
},
"Endpoints": {
  "Https": {
    "Url": "https://<my domain>:443",
    "Certificate": {
      "Path": "/etc/ssl/certificate.pfx",
      "Password": "",
      "AllowInvalid": false
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: No, at a fundamental level, your domain name will be used to find your IP address so a connection can be established. Making your server inaccessible from that IP address will make it inaccessible from your domain as well. In practice, there are ways to obscure the *actual* IP of the server by having your domain point at the IP of a proxy device/system that internally knows where to find your server, but that proxy IP must still be accessible. Could you please clarify your question if this is not what you're asking about.

Comment: That is what I was talking about! I thought the same, this morning I tried setting up the app with nginx as a reverse proxy behind it. I couldn't get that working however. Still think that using that proxy it will resolve this issue I think?

Comment: Yes, you're likely looking for a reverse proxy. Your domain will point at the IP of the proxy provider and your server's IP will be known by the proxy provider. I'm not familiar with how to implement/configure them, so I can't comment on NGINX vs CloudFlare etc.

Comment: I finally got the nginx thing working! So it seems to be working!

Comment: Thanks for updating us that your issue is resolved now. I suggest you could post your solution as an answer to this question. It could help other community members in the future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: For me the solution was to go back to NGINX and solve it in the config there with a reverse proxy, using the instructions on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0) from the official Microsoft docs.